# A curried version of union for a fold?

Tags: haskell, currying

I have this simple version of a set union

```
union (s, []) = s 
union (s, t:ts) | member (t,s) = union (s,ts) 
                | otherwise = t : union (s,ts)
```

where `member` is a version of `elem`. But this, which I found in a textbook, says the `union` must be a curried `union`

```
uniteElems [] = []
uniteElems (h:t) = union h (uniteElems t)
```

This has me confused. As the text says, `uniteElems` is a sort of proto-fold (foldr?), i.e., it should take a single list and recursively apply `union`, thereby weeding out the duplicates. So is this my "curried version" of a union

```
union2 s []                 = s
union2 s (t:ts) | elem t s  = union2 s ts
                | otherwise = union2 (t:s) ts
```

In any event, this `union2` doesn't work as-is in `uniteElems`, giving an error.

```
     * Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [a]
:       (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
:     * When checking the inferred type
:         it :: forall a. (Eq a, Num [a]) => [a]
```

This version, however, does work

```
uniteElems [] = []
uniteElems (h:t) = union2 [h] (uniteElems t)
```

but I've kludged in the `[h]`. What would make `uniteElems`, a sort of proto-fold, work? How would a union function look for regular use with `foldr` would be another related question, I suppose.

Comment: "doesn't work ... giving an error" - always always always include error messages you see. They exist to explain what the problem is. It makes it loads easier for anyone to help with your question.

Comment: You're talking about (subtly) different semantics. Beware that a List is a dodgy way to represent a set (and I wish beginner material didn't do that): in `union (s, t)` does `s` considered alone contain duplicates? Does `t` considered alone contain duplicates? Do `s`, `t` contain duplicates between them, even if no duplicates considered alone? What result do you want from your `union` for each permutation/combination of those delinquent scenarios?

Comment: Consider it `(h U (h U (h U ... (h U [ ])...)` where the `U` is union as an infix (curried two-variable function) and `h` is the head of the list for each recursion. So in effect, it needs to treat the `h` as a list to be matched with the ever-shrinking tail. And yes, it would then pass over duplicates of `h`. But that's my problem, `h` shouldn't be a list,rather, just by itself. Need a version of `union` that isn't a list, just the head itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion in your code over the desired meaning (purpose, or *semantics*) of your various functions.  Related to that, there is definitely some confusion over the *types* of the functions.

Let's start with `uniteElems`.  It seems to have type `Eq a => [a] -> [a]` along with some documented guarantee that the input list is a regular old list while the output list is actually a set.  It relies on there existing a function `union :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]`.  Looking at the definition of `uniteElems`, it seems to be that this `union` function should take an element and a set (represented as a list) and add the element to the set.

Now, let's look at your definition of `union2` (or similar for `union`, just uncurried).  It has type `Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]`, and its meaning seems to be that if it is given two lists that represent sets, it will return a list representing the union of the two sets.

Right away, it seems pretty clear what the problem is: the `union` expected in `uniteElems` and the `union2` you have defined are fundamentally different!  One is adding a single element to a set and the other is combining two whole sets.

Now, it also seems clear why your proposed modification to `uniteElems` works: basically, you're taking each individual element, turning it into a singleton set, and then using your `union2` function to combine those sets.

In order to make `uniteElems` do what you want, you need a simpler definition of `union`, like:

```hs
union :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
union t s | elem t s  = s
          | otherwise = t:s
```

As for folds and proto-folds, `uniteElems` is a protofold because it is essentially a fold where some of the arguments have been supplied.  That is, you could write:

```hs
uniteElems = foldr union []
```

Comment: It was late. I was tired.